# Squeeze space between footnote mark and footnote text with foot

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

I've noticed that using the option `\usepackage[para]{footmisc}` slightly increases the amount of space between the footnote mark and the footnote text. Here's a MWE with which to creat the effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
Text\footnote{A footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Without `footmisc`, I get this:
[image: Without footmisc]

With `footmisc`, I get this:
[image: With footmisc]

Note that I'm not at all worried about the change in the margin. What I don't like is the larger space between the 1 and the letter A.

Is there a command to fix this?  Various `footmisc` options didn't seem to work and, though adding `\hskip-0.25em` to the footnote text seemed to help, it's not an ideal solution...

Comment: It seems related to the `para` option.  Is that option a requirement of yours?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, it basically is. I'm writing a document that requires the references are displayed as footnotes so I want to use `footmisc`'s `para` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I employ a fixed negative kern at the beginning of each footnote.  I also note that the issue seems related to the `para` option of the `footmisc` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\let\svfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnote[2][\relax]{\ifx\relax#1%
  \svfootnote{\kern-4.5pt#2}\else\svfootnote[#1]{\kern-4.5pt#2}\fi}
\begin{document}

Text\footnote{This}
Text\footnote{is}
Text\footnote{a}
Text\footnote{test}
Text\footnote{of}
Text\footnote{the}
Text\footnote{emergency}
Text\footnote{broadcast}
Text\footnote{system}
Text\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From my investigations for [Reduce the space between inline footnotes style=verbose-inote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/504573/35864).

The space between footnote marker and footnote text is hard-coded in `footmisc` with the `para` option as `0.5em` in

```
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\leavevmode
  \@makefnmark\nobreak
  \hskip.5em\relax#1%
}
```

To remove the space, just remove the `\hskip.5em\relax` from the definition. Of course you can just decrease the value if you want to keep some space. Don't forget the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` if you redefine the macro in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\leavevmode
  \@makefnmark\nobreak
  #1%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem\footnote{lorem}
ipsum\footnote{ipsum}
dolor\footnote{dolor}
sit\footnote{sit}
\end{document}
```

[image: No space between footnote marker and text.]