# Reduce the space between inline footnotes style=verbose-inote

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, footmisc

I am using biblatex with style=verbose-inote to have all the references as footnotes. I already characterized some performance but I am not able to reduce the space in-between the last footnote and the following mark.

```
\usepackage[stable,para,hang]{footmisc}

\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,maxcitenames=1,backend=bibtex,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[r]{\smartcite}{\smartcites}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}\addnbspace #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace #1}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%<---- was \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
```

This is the result that I have:

[image: with this the result that I have is like:]

And I want to have shorter space between for example footnote 1 and the mark of footnote 2 because I have a page restriction extension.

Also, can you tell me how to reduce the separation of the footnote mark and the first name letter?

Comment: Can you please extend your code snippet to a fully compilable example document that reproduces the output you see? (Please test the [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) in an empty folder before submission.)

Comment: Also am I right in thinking this is only about the footnotes and footnote marks and the spaces involved there and not at all about `biblatex` and the citation output?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/389347/35864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space between footnote number and footnote text is hard-coded in `\@makefntext` as `.5em`

```
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\leavevmode
  \@makefnmark\nobreak
  \hskip.5em\relax#1%
}
```

You can modify the space and if you want no space at all between footnote mark and text you can completely remove the `\hskip`.

The space between footnotes is controlled by `\footglue` whose predefined value is

```
\footglue=1em plus.3em minus.3em
```

you can change that as you see fit.

For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[stable,para,hang]{footmisc}

\makeatletter
\footglue=.5em plus.15em minus.15em

\long\def\@makefntext#1{\leavevmode
  \@makefnmark\nobreak
  #1%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem\footnote{lorem}
ipsum\footnote{ipsum}
dolor\footnote{dolor}
sit\footnote{sit}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tightly-spaced footnotes]

Comment: It works!  Thank you very much moewe!