# Create and format inline footnotes inside minipages

Tags: formatting, footnotes, minipage

I am trying to create and format some inline footnotes inside minipages. I looked at some questions like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504573/reduce-the-space-between-inline-footnotes-style-verbose-inote) but it seems that they are not working in the minipage environment. Is there a way to format inline footnotes in minipage environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[stable,para,hang]{footmisc}

\makeatletter
\footglue=.5em plus.15em minus.15em

\long\def\@makefntext#1{\leavevmode
  \@makefnmark\nobreak
  #1%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
Lorem\footnote{lorem}
ipsum\footnote{ipsum}
dolor\footnote{dolor}
sit\footnote{sit}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

For in-line footnotes I mean the footnote one next to the other, while I get footnotes one below the other, in the picture below an example of both types:

[image]

**I am trying to achieve two levels of inline footnotes, like the previous image but with the second level inline**

Comment: it is unclear what you want to do. To me, this question seems to already answer it  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274/can-i-get-a-normal-footnote-in-a-minipage-environment-in-latex-how

Comment: do you want the footnote to appear under the `minipage` env?

Comment: @anis I have added an image, I would like inline footnotes inside minipages env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the inline format to all footnotes of the document using:

```
\documentstyle[fnpara]{article}

\begin{document}

Lorem\footnote{lorem} ipsum\footnote{ipsum} 
\bigskip

\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
Lorem\footnote{lorem}
ipsum\footnote{ipsum}
dolor\footnote{dolor}
sit\footnote{sit}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not seems to work for me, the footnotes are below not inline

Comment: Maybe some package is clashing? I tried with LiveTeX and Overleaf and it works with this preamble

Comment: Thanks a lot kekko, yes probably that's the problem still don't work in my project probably due to endnotes and footmisc. But indeed is a good solution! Thanks!

Comment: However, documentstyle seems obsolete

Comment: Yes, it comes from an old application of a dirty rule in the TeXBook specifically for when you have a lot of footnotes. If you go to appendix D there is the code for the macro. I'm not yet that kind of hacker to make a new one from that but maybe you know how to do it (or maybe with a new question someone here could do something?). If you find a solution let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Not a great answer but if there is no way to do it and you are desperate, you can fake the footnote style with something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[para]{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}

Lorem\textsuperscript{a}
ipsum\textsuperscript{b}
dolor\textsuperscript{c}
sit\textsuperscript{d}

\rule [-1.4ex]{6.7cm}{0.4pt}
 \begin{tablenotes}
  \item [a] lorem
  \item [b] ipsum 
  \item [c] dolor
  \item [c] sit
  \end{tablenotes}
 
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That could be a solution, unfortunately, is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Otherwise you can apply the inline format to all footnotes of the document using ```\documentstyle[fnpara]{article}```

Comment: Thanks a lot kekko! can you please provide a working example? It does not seem to work for me.